# Use tf.gather to get the values of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape (2, 3), say `input = [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]`, I have a index tensor of shape (2, 3) which I hope to be used to retrieve the values from input, `index = [[1 0] [2 0]]`. My expected result is `result = [[2 1] [6 4]]`. However, simply using `tf.gather(input, index)` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract element from the array, you can use `gather_nd` and the index should be of the form `(i,j)` for each element. In your example, your index should be:

```
inputs = tf.Variable([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
index = tf.Variable([[[0,1],[0,0]], [[1,2],[1,0]]])

result = tf.gather_nd(inputs, new_index)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print(result.eval())
# output
# [[2 1]
# [6 4]]
```

If you want to generate the index from the form you have mentioned, you can do:

```
index = tf.Variable([[1, 0], [2, 0]])

r = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(index1)[0]), 1), [1, 2])
new_index = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(r,-1), tf.expand_dims(index, -1)], axis=2)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print(new_index.eval())
#output
#[[[0 1]
#[0 0]]
#[[1 2]
#[1 0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `index`, you have to use 0 or 1 values in `index` only, because your `input` array has shape `(2,3)`. If you add additional row to `input` array all work fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.Variable([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
index = tf.Variable([[1, 0], [2, 0]])
result = tf.gather(input, index)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(result))
# results [[[4 5 6] [1 2 3]] [[7 8 9] [1 2 3]]]
```

Anyway, `index` describe which *slice* gather from `input` array, not which *element*.